# Use C++ dll in pycharm

Tags: python, c++, dll, pycharm

I’m writing some python code for which I need to access a c++ dll(.so file)

I’m working on pycharm and I’ve already added the library path to my project by following these steps: (settings>project interpreter>Add new interpreter path)
when i run the code

```
self._bridgeLink = cdll.LoadLibrary(‘foo.so’)
```

Or

```
 self._bridgeLink = cdll.LoadLibrary(‘./foo.so’)
```

It gives me an error saying

`OSError: foo.so : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: 2 things you need to check. (1) Is everything all 32-bit or all 64-bit as you can't mix-and-match?  (2) Do you have all the dependencies that foo.so requires?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are posting suggests that your .so file is not next to your working directory. Try an absolute path to the .so file for testing for now.

You should also check which compiler was used to compile python, you should use the same major version is the Compiler (there are some exception, but that's not the problem for now)